# How do fillings change their state once they are put in mouth? (possibly related with lasers)

Tags: optics, condensed-matter, material-science, laser

I recently seen a dentist for my filling, I for the first time paid attention to what he was doing I guess, because the material he used for my filling was easily deformable before he put it on my teeth (like clay), however it was/and still is pretty solid in my mouth.

**Conjecture**

- I've seen him using ultraviolet laser, I presume he excited the material with UV somehow thus changed the state of the material, yet I don't know how.

I've done some search on internet yet couldn't find anything relevant.

Comment: Google "uv cured dental cement", or just "uv cured" for adhesives, etc. See [Dental cement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dental_cement), [Dental curing light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dental_curing_light), and [What is the blue light all about?](https://www.rexburgappletreedental.com/blog/curing-light)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Composites are placed while still in a soft, dough-like state, but
> when exposed to light of a certain blue wavelength (typically 470
> nm[6]), they polymerize and harden into the solid filling (for more
> information, see Light activated resin)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dental_composite#Method_and_clinical_application